# importing some dependencies as module

Tags: android, module, dependencies

I have opened this github project [trovebox](https://github.com/photo/mobile-android). Since `import com.actionbarsherlock.app.*` can't be resolved, it needs as a dependencie this project `[actionbarsherlock][2]`. But when I try to add this latter as a module (opening the `module settings`), I get an `Empty Library` message. Am I doing right to make this `import com.actionbarsherlock.app.*` recognized ?

Answer (score 0):

You need to load trovebox project submodules and add them as Android Library Projects